# Как можно узнать число ядер, задействованных программой, в ОС Linux?

Tags: linux, процесс

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то узнать, сколько ядер процессора задействует многопоточная программа?

Время ее работы занимает не более 1 секунды, поэтому получить такую информацию с помощью утилит вроде ps для меня проблематично. Возможно, есть какие-нибудь иные способы? Спасибо.

Comment: Можете поискать в /proc/ (see [man 5 proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)), но я не уверен, что ОС сохраняет статистику по использованию потоками ядер. Кстати, ps и т.п. используют для вывода отчета ту же информацию, что содержится в /proc/ и выводят **текущую** привязку процесса к cpu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такую статистику можно получить командой time.

Тут правда не скажешь 8 ядер по 25% или 4 по 50% или 2 по 100%, но в целом можно судить о нагрузке

Запуск

```
$ /usr/bin/time --verbose 7za b
```

Вывод программы 7za

```
7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=ru_RU.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz (406E3),ASM,AES-NI)

Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz (406E3)
CPU Freq: 64000000 - - - - - - - -

RAM size:    3780 MB,  # CPU hardware threads:   4
RAM usage:    882 MB,  # Benchmark threads:      4

                       Compressing  |                  Decompressing
Dict     Speed Usage    R/U Rating  |      Speed Usage    R/U Rating
         KiB/s     %   MIPS   MIPS  |      KiB/s     %   MIPS   MIPS

^C22:       7786   313   2417   7575
```

Вывод команды time

```
Break signaled
Command exited with non-zero status 255
    Command being timed: "7za b"
    User time (seconds): 26.41
    System time (seconds): 0.16
    Percent of CPU this job got: 344%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:07.71
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 120140
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 5847
    Voluntary context switches: 8434
    Involuntary context switches: 5924
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 255
```

Тут видно что программа скушала все ядра  (у меня их 4) Percent of CPU this job got: 344%

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью команды [top](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top)

При запуске команды нажмите цифру **1**

Также, можно использовать [u для просмотра](https://losst.pro/komanda-top-v-linux) процесса определенного пользователя

Comment: К сожалению, я физически не успеваю увидеть нужную мне информацию, поскольку работа программы слишком быстро завершается... Согласно утилите time (из /usr/bin/time), время работы программы составляет ~80 мс

Comment: Что странно. top не должна сама по себе завершаться